What does "Zenescope" in "Zenescope Entertainment" mean?
For those of you who are not in the know, Zenescope Entertainment is a comic book company founded by Joe Brusha and Ralph Tedesco in 2005. This company is best known for "Grimm Fairy Tales" and the other stories attached to it. If you are looking for stories that offer supernatural stuff, horror, superheroes, or a combination of the three, this company has the stuff for you.
Anyway, what I would like to know is what the word "Zenescope" means. I tried to Google it, but there is nothing. I am pretty sure that there is no entry for it in any dictionary. I would not be surprised if Mr. Brusha and Mr. Tedesco coined the word themselves. Even so, that begs the question as to how they came up with this word.
I hope someone here knows more about it than I do.

I've emailed them to ask. Hopefully we'll get a prompt response.

This is a wild guess. Sometimes made-up words that start with "Z" are inspired by Greek words that start with "X." So looking up Xene one gets: French -xène, from Greek -xenos stranger, from xenos.

My new friend Patty, at Zenescope Entertainment, was kind enough to answer this for me. In short, it's a compound of 'Zen' and 'Scope'.

Zenescope was chosen to reflect the balance of creativity and business. 'Zen' is the art we pour into our stories and 'Scope' is the broader vision of connecting those stories with fans everywhere.
We are celebrating our 20th anniversary next year!


Thank you so much for that, Mx. Valorum! I have read a number of stories by Zenescope. I agree that they have a lot of art in them, especially pin-up art, and that these stories have lots of connections between them. Then again, that's what happens when you have the large majority take place in one universe, isn't that right?
